# Using Shopify API to create product in PHP

Tags: php, curl, shopify

Thanks a lot for your solutions. I am using Shopify API along with PHP CURL POST Method to create product. The following is the code and output.

```
$products_array = array(
    "product"=>array(
        'title'=>'',
        "title"=> "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
        "body_html"=> "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
        "vendor"=> "Burton",
        "product_type"=> "Snowboard",
        "published"=> false ,
        "variants"=>array(
                        array(
                        "sku"=>"t_009",
                        "price"=>20.00,
                        "grams"=>200,
                        "taxable"=>false,
                        )
        )
    )
);
echo json_encode($products_array);
echo "<br />";
$url = "https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/products.json";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($products_array));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
```

Where I am using my credentials given in $url part. I am getting following error

```
{"product":{"title":"Burton Custom Freestlye 151","body_html":"Good snowboard!<\/strong>","vendor":"Burton","product_type":"Snowboard","published":false,"variants":[{"sku":"t_009","price":20,"grams":200,"taxable":false}]}}

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 07:28:58 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Sorting-Hat-PodId: 0
X-Sorting-Hat-ShopId: 7628323
X-Sorting-Hat-PodId-Cached: 0
X-Sorting-Hat-ShopId-Cached: 0
Status: 400 Bad Request
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=/xss-report/2dfd1c1e-6c9c-4024-a9bf-f3f6b177eb17?source%5Baction%5D=create&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fproducts&source%5Bsection%5D=admin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-ShopId: 7628323
X-ShardId: 0
X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit: 1/40
HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT: 1/40
X-Stats-UserId: 0
X-Stats-ApiClientId: 619259
X-Stats-ApiPermissionId: 9949639
X-Request-Id: 2dfd1c1e-6c9c-4024-a9bf-f3f6b177eb17
X-Kafka-Logged: 1

{"errors":{"product":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing `Accept: application/json` to `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Thank you for this small little bug. I will take care of such next time. Cheers!!

Comment: Bundles of thank both of you "Josh Brown" and "Pundit".